# MYSQL Select row if value found in any column of a particular table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch all rows from a particular table if value found in any column of the particular table.

Comment: You can try to match your value with every single column. But may I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: If you know the answer tell me.By mistake I put that one.Don't put that type of comments

Answer (score 8):

you can just use `IN`. eg

```
SELECT *
FROM tbName
WHERE yourValue IN (column1, column2, column3, ....)
```

Comment: can we  fetch column names of table automatically and append to this query?

Comment: what if we have 50 columns in one table ?

Comment: @Prabha, then you need to have a dynamic query to get all column names in your table. Here's a demo that you can wrap in Stored procedure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40c81/7

Comment: @JohnWoo Interesting query!! can we do like pattern match for value? EG: where '%yourvalue%' in (col1,col2)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `EXISTS` to do your job.

Below query will get the stores name only if city 2 has a name.

SELECT store_name FROM stores WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM cities WHERE id = 2);