# check if the value in any of these columns mysql

Tags: mysql

I got table called 'pet' have the following values

```
id | name | nickname | dateofborn |
1  | test | jhon     | 2009       |
2  | test2| test     | 2010       |
3  | mike | NULL     | 2010       |
3  | jhon | testor   | 2011       |
```

I want to select all of columns that contain 'test' value either in name column or nickname column so i have this query didn't actually work for me:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name='test' OR nickname= 'test'
```

note that I exactly want test value not testor.

Comment: "draw" an expected results

Comment: Looks good to me. Carry on.

Comment: *i want to select all of columns* unfortunately mysql query select rows (records) not columns. and as @M0rtiis noticed: show us expected result, because your query looks good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL Select row if value found in any column of a particular table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463414/mysql-select-row-if-value-found-in-any-column-of-a-particular-table)

Answer (score 0):

The query is right, I think you have some problems with your Table.

But try like below:

```
USE [yourDB es: animals];

SELECT * FROM [yourDB].pet WHERE (name='test' OR nickname='test');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
    SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name like 'test%' OR nickname like 'test'
```